# flatten a named list in R - converting the name into first column

Tags: r, list, data.table, radix

Say, I have a named list:

```
library(dplyr)
myData <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_map(~ head(.x, 1L))
names(myData) <- c("Mazda", "Honda", "Suzuki")
```

Now, I want to convert the list into a table looking like this:

```
name  mpg disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1:  Mazda 22.8  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
2:  Honda 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
3: Suzuki 18.7  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

I tried:

```
data.frame(Reduce(rbind, myData))
do.call(rbind.data.frame, myData)
```

but the both result in a data.table without the names. How can I convert the list into a data.table with the column `names`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(myData, idcol = "name")
#      name  mpg disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1:  Mazda 22.8  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 2:  Honda 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 3: Suzuki 18.7  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Or in base R:

```
data.frame(name = names(myData), do.call(rbind, myData))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(myData, .id = 'name')
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
cbind(
  name = names(myData),
  do.call(rbind, c(myData, use.names = FALSE))
)
```

giving

```
    name  mpg disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  Mazda 22.8  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
2  Honda 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
3 Suzuki 18.7  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# data:
library(tidyverse)
myData <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    group_map(~ head(.x, 1L))
names(myData) <- c("Mazda", "Honda", "Suzuki")
```

In `purrr::imap`, the tilde-shortcut (`~`), makes `.x` refer to the input, while `.y` refer to the names of the input. The `_dfr`-suffix makes the map function return a tibble instead of a list.

```
myData |> 
    imap_dfr(~ mutate(.x, name = .y))
```

giving:

```
#> # A tibble: 3 × 11
#>     mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb name  
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1  22.8   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1 Mazda 
#> 2  21     160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 Honda 
#> 3  18.7   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2 Suzuki
```